# PHP displaying wrong username

Tags: php, mysql

I working on a secured blog where I have a specific post displayed in separate page once a user clicks read more button. This separate page includes registered users comments.The issue I have is that the name of the user who wrote the comment is not matching the actual user, its showing instead a name of a user who wrote a post. My sql query:

```
$comsql="SELECT c.*,u.name FROM posts p JOIN users u ON p.user_id=u.id"
    ." JOIN comments c on p.id=c.post_id ORDER BY commentdate DESC";
```

My echo:]

**Written by:** , On:    ">Edit comment | ">Delete comment

Comment: My echo:]<?php foreach ($comments as $comm): ?>  
    
    <?php if($comm['post_id']==$post['id']):?> 
    <div class="sidebar-box-com"> 
    <p><?= htmlentities($comm['comment']); ?></p>  
    <p><b>Written by: </b><i><?= $comm['name']; ?></i>, On: <?= $comm['commentdate']; ?> 
        <?php if ($comm['user_id']== $uid): ?>  
    <span class="editdelcom"> 
        <a href="edit_comment.php?id=<?= $comm['id']; ?>">Edit comment</a> | 
    <a href="delete_comment.php?id=<?= $comm['id']; ?>">Delete comment</a>

Comment: You should edit your question to add that comment

Comment: As Machavtiy wrote [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43458709/edit) your question and include the code there

Comment: question's too unclear and if the query was executed and with api is used to connect with. There is also no `WHERE` clause, seeing you want to query for a user in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's what you ask:

```
ON p.user_id=u.id
```

You should have somthing like this:

```
ON c.user_id=u.id
```

In your SQL query you're matching the user of the post instead of the user of the comment. Do you have a `user_id` field in the `comments` table ?

Comment: nope,that's not it ...when i do that its not displaying the comments at all

Comment: Can we see the structure of your `comments` table ?

Comment: it has id,post_id,user_id,comment,commentdate

Comment: You said that your were on a specific blog post page ? Where do you say in your query `where p.id=XXX` ?

Comment: Well I am joining tables, is it necessary? If yes please advise where I should putt it,tnx

Comment: Yes it is necessary. Your database don't know which comments do you want ? Of what post ? Instead it will returns all the comments of your table.

How do you know the right blog post to show comments ? Is you URL looks something like `blog.php?post=1` ?

If so you can try this SQL query:

`SELECT c.*,u.name FROM posts p JOIN users u ON c.user_id=u.id JOIN comments c on p.id=c.post_id WHERE p.id=XXX ORDER BY commentdate DESC";`

Where XXX is the id if the post.

Comment: I have a dynamic id ,I pulled it with $GET and stored it in $post['id'] ...you can see it in my echo

Comment: Did you try to replace XXX from my previous response by `$post['id']` ?

Comment: Is this what you mean: $comsql="SELECT c.*,u.name FROM posts p JOIN users u ON c.user_id=u.id JOIN comments c on p.id=c.post_id WHERE p.id={$post['id']} ORDER BY commentdate DESC";

Comment: Yes this should works. If no, please edit your post and add more code so we can understand what' happening.

Comment: using this query leads to none comments displayed at all . What other code should I post ?

Comment: Try the query directly in your database (using PhpMyAdmin or the mysql command line directly). Did you have results ? Are they correct ? If no can we have a sample of you comments table ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, both comments and users tables have name field. To fix this;

Change query to:

```
$comsql="SELECT c.*,u.name AS username FROM posts p JOIN users u ON p.user_id=u.id"
    ." JOIN comments c on p.id=c.post_id ORDER BY commentdate DESC";
```

If doesn't work, please leave a comment

Comment: my comments table doesn't have a name field... it has id,post_id,user_id,comment,commentdate

Comment: @IlonaSemy can you also change $comm['name'] to $comm['username'] with same query above?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand exactly what you mean,should I change $comm['name'] to $comm['username'] inside my echo?

Comment: @IlonaSemy In this case, what I can offer is, execute your query using phpmyadmin console and try to figure out. It's hard to understand without seeing output.